# Zomato API integration with in android app

Tags: android, zomato-api

```
{
    "code":403,
    "status":"Forbidden",
    "message":"Invalid API Key"
}
```

[this is what i am getting as request URL](https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories)

I am trying to use the request URL for Zomato API using my Generated API key.  But every time i  try to use the URL on fiddler and any browser it is showing this error of `INVALID API KEY`.

Why i am getting this invalid API key and how can i solve it?

> EDITED:
>   this image might clear how i am using the key

[image: this image might clear how i am using the key]

> xxxxx is just an example . This is how i am using the api key and then using the URL!

Comment: plz guys really need help

Comment: Maybe the API key is linked to a specific domain or app? How are you giving the API key to Zomato?

Comment: add some coding part after that we can tell you exactly. currently, we can only say that your API key is invalid

Comment: what you are using for network call

Comment: actually i am trying to make a restaurant finder app . That's why i want to use this API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing api key in parameters makes it difficult for clients to keep their APIkeys secret, they tend to leak keys on a regular basis. A better approach is to pass it in header of request url. You can set user-key header in your code equals to your api key. For testing your request Url you can use Postman app in google chrome.

send a get request to your endpoint by setting user-key header to your api-key.
You can refer to this postman screenshot to see it is working:

[image]

Comment: Sir can you share some code how to use that Zomato API in android. And how to use that request url with api-key in the header.

Answer (score 0):

According to Zomato API https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/common/categories you shoud pass your API key in header

you can get an API key from here: https://developers.zomato.com/api#headline2

Comment: Sir, i have the API key and in the documentation part of Zomato API , I've already used the key in the parameter section. And then i am using the request URL. I am not getting what you are telling me!!